# Laravel пагинация

Tags: php, laravel

Как реализовать пагинацию в Laravel 8, чтобы в адресной строке было: mysite.com/page/1, а не ?page=1?

Сейчас контроллер выглядит следующим образом:

```
    <?php


    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
    use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

    use App\Models\Goods as Items;

    class Goods extends Controller {

        public function index() {

            //  Список всех товаров
            $goods = Items::leftJoin('categories', function($item) {
                $item->on('goods.good_category', '=', 'categories.category_id');
            })->get();

            //  Количество товаров на странице
            $perPage = 10;

            //  Указатель на текущую страницу
            $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

            //  Создание экземпляра пагинатора
            $pagination = new LengthAwarePaginator($goods, sizeof($goods), $perPage, $currentPage);

            //  Устанавливаем ссылку
            $pagination->setPath('page');

            //  Получаем коллекцию записей с постраничным отображением
            $goods = $pagination->getCollection();

            //  Отдаем данные в представление
            return view('goods', ['goods' => 'goods']);

        }
    }
```

В шаблоне пытаюсь выполнить следующий код:

```
{{ $goods->render() }}
```

И получаю ошибку: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::render does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить роут

```
Route::get('page/{page}', [...])
```

а в самом методе использовать запросы take и offset в зависимости от page